# Updating React 18 app to createRoot breaks mutations in TanStack/query

Tags: reactjs, react-query, react-18

I use `TanStack/query` to handle mutations for registration/login to a Drupal 9 website.

If registration is successful, I automatically log the user in.

With React 17, the following code allows the user to register and then immediately logs the user in.  However, with React 18 and [createRoot](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-client-rendering-apis), registration succeeds but login fails because `onSuccess` no longer has access to the variable `formData` (`console.log()` in `onSuccess` returns an empty object for `formData`).

```
const onSubmit = (submitData: DrupalLoginFormInput) => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  mutateRegister.mutate(submitData);
};

export const useMutationRegister = (
  formData: DrupalLoginFormInput,
  setIsLoading: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>,
): UseMutationResult<HttpResponse, string, DrupalLoginFormInput> => {
  const mutateLogin = useMutationLogin();
  return useMutation(
    (registerData: DrupalLoginFormInput) =>
      postRegisterUser(registerData, platform),
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        // console.log('mutateRegister succeeded', response, formData);
        // Log in with the newly registered info.
        const registeredDataToLogin = {
          mail: formData.mail,
          pass: formData.pass,
        };
        mutateLogin.mutate(registeredDataToLogin);
      },
    },
  );
};

export type DrupalLoginFormInput = {
  mail: string;
  pass: string;
};
```

The [React 18 batching deep dive](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21) suggests using `flushSync()` to disable batching, so I tried this:

```
const onSubmit = (submitData: DrupalLoginFormInput) => {
  flushSync(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    mutateRegister.mutate(submitData);
  });
};
```

However, login is still broken (`formData` is not available in `onSuccess`).

If I keep my app with React 18 but revert `createRoot()` to the old way (`render(<App />, container);`), then login works again.  However, I want to use `createRoot()` because that unlocks the new React 18 features.

How can I fix my code so that the `formData` variable doesn't get removed before I access it in `onSuccess`?

Comment: we haven't changed anything in this regard from v3 to v4. It would be good if you could show a minimal codesandbox reproduction that works with v3 but fails with v4, thanks.

Comment: @TkDodo Ok, thanks.  It may have been in upgrading react or react-hook-form then.  I will try to isolate the issue and make a codesandbox.

Comment: @TkDodo Traced the problem to `createRoot()` in React 18.  This is not a v3/v4 issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `flushSync()` incorrectly.  You need to call `flushSync()` each time you want the DOM to update.

Bad code:

```
const onSubmit = (submitData: DrupalLoginFormInput) => {
  flushSync(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    mutateRegister.mutate(submitData);
  });
};
```

Good code, state updates correctly:

```
const onSubmit = (submitData: DrupalLoginFormInput) => {
  flushSync(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
  });
  flushSync(() => {
    mutateRegister.mutate(submitData);
  });
};
```